# Manage relations among users in db

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, database

I am creating a mock app with user creation/auth/friend in a node js learning exercise. Having spent my time mostly at the front end of things, I am a n00b as far as DBs are concerned. I want to create a user database where I want to keep track of user profiles and their connections/friends.

Primary objective is to load/store users connections in the database. 
Fetch this information and give it to the user most efficiently in least number of queries.

I'd really appreciate some help with a DB structure I should be using that can accomplish this. I am using mongodb and node.

Off the top of my head: I can store the user's connections in an object in the "connections" field. But this will involve making a lot of queries to fetch connections' details like their "about me" information - which I can also store in the same object as well.

Confused. Would really appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mongoose ORM. It has a populate method that grabs foreign documents. Lots of other great stuff too.

You could say

```
Users.find({}).populate('connections').exec(function(err,users) { ... });
```

Before popualte the users' array of connections was an array of IDs, after, its an array of user documents.